# Can not see the relevant pages in the test results

Tags: loadrunner

The script is recorded and played successfully. But when I look at the test results I do not see the relevant pages only homepage is shown.I am using Web/HTML protocol.

I am running the tests from VU Generator. I am trying to review the test results from the Test Result link present in Replay Summary tab.

Comment: Do you see the relevant steps in the script? Each web_XXX (where XXX can be one of url, custom_request, etc...) means a call to the server.

Comment: Yes, I do see the steps.

Comment: But there are two types of requests to the server,GET & OPTIONS. The response from OPTIONS request is blank.Not sure why LR is recording the OPTIONS request("Method=OPTIONS") as opposed to GET request? Might be this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot help without seeing the script. Please open a support ticket.

Comment: Hi Buzzy, I am new to this forum, how can I open the support ticket? Can I post the script in the comment box here?

Comment: Please post your question on the official LoadRunner support forum: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/LoadRunner-Support-Forum/bd-p/sws-LoadRunner_SF